# Cloudera QuickStart VM Error

Tags: apache-hadoop

I have installed cloudera CDH5 Quick start VM on VM player. When I login through HUE in the first page I am the following error

“Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.”[image: Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue]

How to solve this issue.

Comment: This is probably better for serverfault.com

Comment: @SeanOwen Yes, or [cloudera support](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/about/contact-form.html), even

Comment: Could you provide the list of misconfigurations (that are just below the yellow bar)?

Comment: FWIW, I just started the 5.1 QuickStart VM and there was no such warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the other link from home - to the cloudera manager.

From there, you'll see Hue can be restarted, but there is probably an alert that needs to be resolved in there first.

If I remember right there's some initial configuration that needs to be done on the quickstart VM that's spelled out as soon as you log into the manager application.

Comment: There's no configuration that is required, or certainly there shouldn't be. The 5.1 VM does not exhibit this.

Answer (score 1):

We faced this problem and analysed the issue.
Cloudera, Hue or Hive didn't have any error reported but the users via Beeswax were unable to run queries.
It was good to analyze below:
Duplicate PID for Hive (check for all hive servers. If you do have a tool to check the duplicate PID then use that or use the kinit to login to cloudera admin node and analyze it.)
We killed the duplicate PID
AND
restarted hive server. It fixed the issue.